# why does the variable reset when a recursive function returns

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have been struggling for days to wrap my head around recursive functions. The below code snippet is part of a Merge Sort lesson I'm trying to teach myself. I used Google Chrome developer tools to step through this code and I see the following parameters passed to the function ms(p,r) in the following order.

ms(0,6),ms(0,3),ms(0,1),ms(0,0)

so far so good...

When the ms() function reaches the dead end, the next function is called with the parameters ms(1,1).

I understand what's going on upto this point.

Next, the variable 'q' has the value ZERO which I don't understand how. I am expecting q=1 because at this point in the code, the expression q=Math.floor((p+r)/2) should still retain the value of q, which is 1.

why does it revert to zero?

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<script>

a = [4,1,6,7,5,2,3];
var q=0;

function ms(p,r){
  if(p<r){
  q=Math.floor((p+r)/2);
  ms(p,q);
  ms(q+1,r);
  m(p,q,r);
  }   
}

function m(p,q,r){
 //do something
}

ms(0,6);

</script>
```

Comment: have you tried some debugging 101 - console.log - to trace what's actually happening in your code

Comment: It is not clear what the actual result and expected result are? _"the expression q=Math.floor((p+r)/2) should still retain the value of q, which is 1"_  At which should do you expect `q` to equal `1`? What do you mean by "revert to zero"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to the last of the first recursive `ms()` `q=Math.floor((0+1)/2)` -> `0` --> `ms(0,0)`. Since `q` is global, its settings are changed, globally. So, within the context of `ms(0,1)`, after its first recursive call, `ms(p,q)`, `q` is 0, so the next call, `ms(q+1,r)` is `ms(0+1,1)` --> `ms(1,1)`.

Is that where your confusion was?

I suspect that you do not want `q` to be global, since you should be splitting the evaluated portion of the array for each iterated call to `ms()`.

```
function ms(p,r) {
  if(p<r){
    var q=Math.floor((p+r)/2);
    ms(p,q);
    ms(q+1,r);
    m(p,q,r);
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am confused about what happens next. after ms(1,1) returns, ms( q+1, r) is called and at this point q should still contain the value 1, and therefore --> ms(1+1,1). but when the debugger is showing is showing that q=0. and yes, I do not want q to be global, although i tried it and it didn't change anything.

Comment: The various calls gets confusing… we should've numbered them. When `ms(q+1,r)` is `ms(1,1)`, it's because `q` is already 0. `ms(1,1)` is a no-op (since p not < r), so, upon it's return, `q` is still 0.

Comment: After going through it a dozen times i think i'm getting it. everything is working as expected. Thank you all for your help!